# Smart way to access a string key dictionary with an integer

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dicts looking like this

```
d = {'NO_AGE': 9073.383207816209, 'AGE_90_TO_94': 10180.890534787184, 'AGE_1_TO_4': 52.038207990747644, 'AGE_55_TO_59': 9478.521660593395, 'AGE_10_TO_14': 182.1538452536723, 'AGE_25_TO_29': 573.790500096642, 'AGE_50_TO_54': 3416.95032267009, 'AGE_80_TO_84': 28129.36979285145, 'AGE_65_TO_69': 17135.56861571398, 'AGE_20_TO_24': 337.2618068826558, 'AGE_60_TO_64': 13330.668158232951, 'AGE_35_TO_39': 1389.974386808924, 'AGE_40_TO_44': 2444.3766299343915, 'AGE_85_TO_89': 46096.18077353476, 'AGE_BELOW_1': 88.26897807095487, 'AGE_5_TO_9': 94.12793975550878, 'AGE_15_TO_19': 422.24788874387224, 'AGE_95_TO_99': 65151.416230644914, 'AGE_30_TO_34': 788.5198247415105, 'AGE_45_TO_49': 3954.548619474476, 'AGE_70_TO_74': 28879.02514167294, 'AGE_75_TO_79': 27326.905372424113}
```

In addition I have the age of a person as an integer e.g.

```
age = 92
```

Is there a smart way to extract the corresponding value (here 10180.89 based on key 'AGE_90_TO_94') from the dict without writing ~20 if/elif statements?

Comment: How is this dictionary formed? If possible, it's better if you can format your dictionary in the first place so that lookup is easier.

Comment: As @Austin said, if you can format your dictionary in a different way, you can go with a single item for each year like dict={0:x,1:x,2:x,3:x,4:y,5:y,6:y} and so on. So you can simply do dict[age] for have the corrispondent number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute the key in just a few cases. Here is one way:

```
def get_key(i):
    if i == 0:
        return 'AGE_BELOW_1'
    elif i <= 4:
        return 'AGE_1_TO_4'
    else:
        a = i - i%5
        b = a + 4
        return 'AGE_' + str(a) + '_TO_' + str(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dictionary is always formatted like this i would go with retrieving the numbers out of the key:

```
def get_answer(age):
  if not age:
     return d['NO_AGE']
  for key, value in d.items():
    if key == 'NO_AGE': continue
    _, begin, _, end = key.split('_')
    if int(begin) <= age <= int(end):
      return value
```

If you have alot of age lookups when d is not changing you can do some caching and make this quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with combination of several things.

```py
my_dict_keys = my_dict.keys()
translate = {}
for key in my_dict_keys:
    if "no" in key.lower():
        translate[0] = key
    else:
        ranges = [] 
        for k in key.split("_"):
            try:
                 ranges.append(int(k))
            except ValueError :
                continue
         translate[range(*ranges)] = key

get_key = lambda value : value for key, values in translates.items() if value in key
```

Not pytonic, but you guess the idea.

- create a dictionary with key as a range and actual dict key as value
- if value (eg : 92) is in key key return the value (the dict key you are looking for)

Answer (score 0):

With short *circuit*:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if k != 'NO_AGE' and '_TO_' in k:
        from_, to_ = k.replace('AGE_', '').replace('_TO_', ' ').split()
        if int(from_) <= age <= int(to_):
            break
else:
    v = None
print(v)   # 10180.890534787184
```

---

On encountering `break` statement - `v` variable is already assigned with the needed value. Otherwise - no matches, `v = None`